# Unable to connect to AD Server?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, ansible, exchange-server

I am trying to execute AD and Exchange commands from my Ansible master server, but I receive below error. I can successfully execute these commands on my windows server locally.

### For AD:

`FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "powershell.exe \"import-module activedirectory;get-aduser -Identity 'testuser01'\" > aa.txt", "delta": "0:00:01.796829", "end": "2019-05-08 12:41:19.824130", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-05-08 12:41:18.027300", "stderr": "get-aduser : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server \r\ndoes not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory \r\nWeb Services running.`

### For Exchange:

`FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn;enable-mailbox 'testuser01' > c:/temp/aa.txt", "delta": "0:00:12.734039", "end": "2019-05-08 01:13:51.726514", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-05-08 01:13:38.992475", "stderr": "Active Directory operation failed on . The supplied credential for \r\n'DEVAD\\admin' is invalid.`

### Code Part

### For AD:

```
- name: Mailbox Creation
  win_shell: "import-module activedirectory;get-aduser -identity 'testuser01'"
```

### For Exchange:

```
- name: Mailbox Creation
  win_shell: "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn;enable-mailbox 'testuser01' > c:/temp/aa.txt"
```

Comment: Do the commands run from powershell? Those errors are typical to firewall blocking.

Comment: Hi Rohin, Commands run from powershell locally

Answer (score 0):

maybe someone help.

have same problem when using kerberos

```
ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos
```

need to turn credential on delegation, tested with kerberos only.

```
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: yes
```

Comment: This option is not available on NTLM authentication and kerberos authentication is kind of a pain when your Ansible server is not in the same domain as the system you are managing.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason accessing the Active Directory from the remote Exchange PowerShell environment doesn't work out of the box, and you have to generate a new session and run your commands within it.

```
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "{{ ansible_password }}" -AsPlainText -Force
$UserCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "{{ ansible_user }}", $PWord

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://{{ inventory_hostname }}/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
```

Followed by your code:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn
...
```

And ended with:

```
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Relevant documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential#example-6